# HTTP barebones web client using http.client and GET method in python

Tags: python, http, curl

I am trying to create barebones web client which only implements the GET method and follows the basics of the HTTP/1.1 specification, enough to download files as one would with the command line program curl with just http.client library. I am trying to do this without using urllib or requests libraries.

I'm aware that HTTP/1.0 describes the most basic functionality that an HTTP client is required to do. HTTP/1.1 includes several new features that extend the protocol.
I want to implement these additional features

- Host header
- Transfer encoding: chunked
- a Connection: close header, or handle persistent connections

Comment: If you wish to do this. Then you should read the relevant rfc documents and implement your client with that information in mind. SO will be here to help if you have any specific questions.

Comment: If this is homework for a job application, keep in mind that employers often check StackOverflow

Comment: Im just trying to learn this, reading the rfc is a bit overwhelming.

Comment: that's not HTTP/1.0. That's a broken HTTP/1.1 support, and you'll learn that doing persistent connections properly will require even more HTTP/1.1 awareness. There's no good shortcut to implementing HTTP/1.1 - read the spec and then compare/see what existing HTTP/1.1 clients do.